# What is the difference between NP and coNP?

Tags: computational-complexity, automata

What is the difference between NP and coNP? Is coNP a subset of NP ? or vice versa? What is the significance of NP $\cap$ coNP when it comes to mathematics?

Comment: Do you know what $NP$ means? If not, I think the book by Sipser on Computational Complexity is well written and suitable for self study.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Co-NP

Comment: You may get more in-depth answers posting to Computer Science Stack Exchange.

Comment: The precise title is " Introduction to the Theory of Computation: Michael Sipser."

Comment: NP means some decision branch returns true in polynomial time.  co-NP means all decision branches return true in polynomial time.

Comment: @ArtimisFowl No.  What I said is correct.  There are 2 kinds of non deterministic machines.  One machine returns true if any branch returns true ($\exists$ type), the other kind only returns true if all branches return true ($\forall$ type)  (Actually there is a kind of machine with both capabilities, but that's beyond the scope of the question).  CoNP says "can this be solved in polytime on a $\forall$ type".  NP asks "can this be solved in polytime on a $\exists$ type".

Answer (score 7):

**NP** is the class of decision problems for which there is a polynomial time algorithm that can **verify** "yes" instances given the appropriate certificate.

**CoNP** is the class of decision problems for which there is a polynomial time algorithm that can **verify** "no" instances given the appropriate certificate.

We don’t know whether coNP is different from NP.

There is a problem in NP for every problem in coNP, and vice versa. For example, the SAT problem asks "does there exist a boolean assignment which makes this formula evaluate to True?". The complement problem, which is in coNP, asks, "do all boolean assignments make this formula evaluate to False?"

Answer (score 5):

There are several definitions that all end up equivalent. However, my favorite has to do with verification. $NP$ is the class of problems where it's easy (read "takes polynomial time, if given help") to verify that there is a solution. For example, it's easy to convince someone that a SAT instance is solvable, just give them a satisfying assignment and they can check if all the clauses are satisfied.

Likewise, $CO-NP$ problems are easy to show that there isn't a solution. For example, checking if a Boolean function is unchanged when we switch the first two inputs. I only need to show you one case where $f(x,y,\cdots) \neq f(y,x,\ldots)$ to show that it's not symmetric, however it's not at all clear how to show if this function **is** symmetric.

Because we can't easily show a SAT instance is unsatisfiable, nor that a function is symmetric, neither $NP$ nor $CO-NP$ is known to be a subset of the other.

Being in both means that you can easily check either way, given a proof (like a satisfying assignment or a counterexample). Examples include every problem we can solve in polynomial time, which require no help to verify, the curious can quickly run a poly time algorithm themselves to verify an answer.